# Forces in a quantum levitation

Tags: superconductivity

When a superconductor is quantumly levitated, what are the forces experienced by the superconductor and magnet?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing magical about the force between the magnet and superconductor. The superconductor feels an upward force equal to $mg$, where $m$ is the mass of the superconductor and $g$ is the gravitational acceleration. Likewise the magnet feels a downwards force of $mg$. The forces experienced are the same as if a spring or something equally mundane was being used to support the superconductor.